# Get loads of errors while Eclipse Emulator loads up

Tags: android, eclipse, android-emulator, adt

I get rather of lot of errors when my Eclipse Android Emulator loads up. I was wondering what I could do to get rid of them.
These are the error messages:

```
01-04 12:51:26.300: E/SurfaceFlinger(953): hwcomposer module not found
01-04 12:51:27.050: E/SurfaceFlinger(953): ro.sf.lcd_density must be defined as a build property
01-04 12:51:40.920: E/logwrapper(1170): executing /system/bin/ip failed: No such file or directory
01-04 12:51:40.970: E/logwrapper(1171): executing /system/bin/ip failed: No such file or directory
01-04 12:51:40.990: E/logwrapper(1174): executing /system/bin/ip failed: No such file or directory
01-04 12:51:41.050: E/logwrapper(1177): executing /system/bin/ip failed: No such file or directory
01-04 12:51:41.080: E/logwrapper(1178): executing /system/bin/ip failed: No such file or directory
01-04 12:51:41.110: E/logwrapper(1179): executing /system/bin/ip failed: No such file or directory
01-04 12:51:41.140: E/logwrapper(1180): executing /system/bin/ip failed: No such file or directory
01-04 12:51:46.410: E/PowerManagerService-JNI(1234): Couldn't load power module (No such file or directory)
01-04 12:51:46.710: E/SurfaceFlinger(953): ro.sf.lcd_density must be defined as a build property
01-04 12:51:52.930: E/libsuspend(1234): Error opening /sys/power/autosleep: No such file or directory
01-04 12:51:53.140: E/WVMExtractor(956): Failed to open libwvm.so
01-04 12:51:53.220: E/EventHub(1234): could not get driver version for /dev/input/mouse0, Not a typewriter
01-04 12:51:53.250: E/EventHub(1234): could not get driver version for /dev/input/mice, Not a typewriter
01-04 12:51:54.190: E/MobileDataStateTracker(1234): default: Ignoring feature request because could not acquire PhoneService
01-04 12:51:54.190: E/MobileDataStateTracker(1234): default: Could not enable APN type "default"
01-04 12:51:55.340: E/SELinux(954): avc:  denied  { specifyids } for  scontext=u:r:system:s0 tcontext=u:r:system:s0 tclass=zygote
01-04 12:51:55.340: E/SELinux(954): avc:  denied  { specifyseinfo } for  scontext=u:r:system:s0 tcontext=u:r:system:s0 tclass=zygote
01-04 12:51:57.710: E/BluetoothAdapter(1310): Bluetooth binder is null
01-04 12:51:57.720: E/BluetoothAdapter(1310): Bluetooth binder is null
01-04 12:51:57.930: E/BluetoothAdapter(1310): Bluetooth binder is null
01-04 12:51:58.970: E/BluetoothAdapter(1310): Bluetooth binder is null
01-04 12:51:59.080: E/VoldConnector(1234): NDC Command {3 volume mount /storage/sdcard} took too long (3692ms)
01-04 12:52:00.560: E/BluetoothAdapter(1310): Bluetooth binder is null
```

Comment: Errors are fine. The emulator does not support Bluetooth/Mobile Data etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to try debugging since the messages aren't very clear as to what is going wrong. Might I also suggest cleaning your project if you haven't done so already? Hope I helped. :)